# ROS hydro, moveit symbol lookup error

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to run pr2 moveit tutorials by launching "roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch"
But rviz start and died in few seconds and console gives following error.
**/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error:
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libmoveit_planning_scene_monitor.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z**
I updated moveit plugin and tried, but problem remains and I am new to ROS and moveIt.
Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166381/ros-hydro,-moveit-symbol-lookup-error/) by [dinesh_sl](https://answers.ros.org/users/18136/dinesh_sl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should make sure all your ROS debians are up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install ros-hydro-*
```

And then if you have a catkin workspace, I would rebuild it entirely by removing the build and devel directories and rebuilding.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh_sl](https://answers.ros.org/users/18136/dinesh_sl/) on 2014-06-17**:
Thank you very much. It worked well.